# Apache airflow running issue in browser (favicon.ico)

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

I am new to apache airflow. I installed airflow locally in my laptop using Windows subsystem for linux, after installation of Python 3 pip and other Dependancies I hit command "airflow webserver -p 8080" on ubuntu terminal. Airflow starts normally, then I open "localhost:8080" on browser it through error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT9Zl.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptkJk.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPdQ1.png)

please help to resolve this error.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized the database or the database configuration does not point to the right database (the error is about missing table in the DB that should have been created by `airflow db upgrade`).

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/setting-up-the-database.html